# How can I control the content of a favicon.ico file?

Tags: browser, web, favicon

I want to edit each single size icon in the file manually so that I get exactly what I want.

Is there a tool that will let me have a merged 16x16, 32x32, 48x48 and 64x64 icon that will let me control the content (the exact pixels) of each size?

I've used some favicon generators and uploaded a 48x48 image but my image does not do well when downsized automatically, it needs human intervention from a designer (me).

Comment: I may have found my answer https://itunes.apple.com/app/icon-slate/id439697913?mt=12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various applications you can download or there are web based editors such as http://www.xiconeditor.com

Comment: Thanks! That looks good. I ended up using Icon Slate, which is not free, but it's great on a mac. Now I just have to figure out how to get that icon to refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You can use free, command line tools. Icoutils:

```
# On Ubuntu
sudo apt-get install icoutils
icotool -c -o favicon.ico 16x16.png 32x32.png 48x48.png 64x64.png
```

ImageMagick:

```
# On Ubuntu
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
convert 16x16.png 32x32.png 48x48.png 64x64.png favicon.ico
# If you use IM version >= 6.8.8-3, you can even resize the original picture
# and create favicon.ico at once:
convert input.png -define icon:auto-resize=64,48,32,16 favicon.ico
```

As an aside, you mention all supported sizes, up to 64x64. Although this size is documented, [Microsoft recommends only 16x16, 32x32 and 48x48](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg491740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). There are reasons to think that the [64x64 picture is never used](http://realfavicongenerator.net/faq#ico_big_enough) (granted, that was tested on Windows 8.1 only).

Keep in mind that [you need a lot of pictures in order to support all platforms](http://realfavicongenerator.net/faq#why_so_many_files): iOS, Android, etc.